# What is the source of Printer Status Events in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printing, event-viewer

While looking at Event Viewer, if I send a file to Print, I can see various entries in the logs regarding spooling and cancelled jobs - all located in:

```
Microsoft->Windows->PrintSystems
```

But if I send a print job to an offline printer or if there is some other error, like the printer having no paper. I see no reference to an event in the Event Viewer, even though I receive a slide in notification in Windows 10.

Is there a different service that handles these?

It seems that something is catching those warnings or dialogs, but I just cant figure out which source is handling them?  It's definitely not `PrintSystems`.

Is there an error logging attribute I am not checking regarding `PrintSystems`? I saw something of the kind in references to Windows 7 but for Windows 10 it seems it has been changed.

The reason is I am trying to create a task referencing these warnings and errors.